# Documentation Proposed Changes Review: no items to review when clicked even if there are in review list

Tags: bug, documentation-review

Today I gave the new Documentation: Proposed Changes Review a shot but I've found something strange.

In my review list, the changes count is 2, but when I click on it to start reviewing I get the message: "There are currently no pending items to review; please check back later.".

This appears not to be a concurrency problem, because if I go back and refresh the page, the counter still says 1 or 2 and I have still the same problem. I've tried a bunch of time and I'm always getting this result. 
BTW, the fact that the counter is changing, makes me think that somebody is able to review.

Is anybody else having this problem?

Comment: I often get the same on other review queues. I think the counts are only generated every few minutes. Enough other people visit and review the entries between the counts being generated and you (or me) opening the queue that all the reviews have been completed. Wait a few minutes, then refresh the page with the counts.

Comment: Yeah, that''s why I've specified that the problem is persistent for me on that specific queue. I get the behavior you are descriving on other queues, but for the documentation queue it's always like that... I've done multiple tests

Comment: Check the filtering - that played the trick with me once... I got 4, but saw none - turned out I had a `[c]` filter...

Comment: Just checked, I have no filters

Comment: @Aurasphere Have you skipped any reviews in that queue recently? I've been running into this too (*only* with the Documentation Proposed Changes queue), and I notice it seems to happen after I skip some reviews.

Comment: No I didn't do any skip. At least I am not the only one experiencing this.

Comment: Actually I just had it happen when I completed some reviews rather than skipping, so that's probably not the cause. But I agree: this has only been happening on the Documentation Proposed Changes queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By studying the history tab I came to the following theory:
The counters are accurate they just don't take into the account that people are reviewing right now all of the proposed changes. The reason I think so is: if you will keep on refreshing the history page you will eventually see a new action. The reason why it's happening to document changes more often is because it's the easiest privilege so the most people have so better chance that someone is looking at it right now.